# Limitar numero de filas de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Que tal amigos, la duda que tengo es la siguiente: Tengo una tabla conectada a una base de datos, cada vez que se le ingresa algun valor se actualiza automaticamente, el problema que tengo es que me muestra todos los valores de la base de datos, como puedo limitar esas filas a que me muestre solo un numero especifico de valores, es decir mientras va actualizando muestra por ejemplo 15 valres, y va ocultando los demas,! no estoy usando Datatables¡

Comment: Buenas @Staz, nos podrías poner el código que hasta ahora estás usando y así analizar mejor tu problema.

También te aconsejo que para siguientes preguntas antes te consultes el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Hola, haz intentado algo? puedes pegar el código para darnos una idea de lo que ncesitas?

Comment: @Staz, **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Usa LIMIT junto con OFFSET: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creo que te refieres a una consulta SQL?

Ejemplo: Con esta consulta vamos a obtener 10 registros de nuestra DB.

```
$var = "SELECT * FROM usuarios LIMIT 10";
```

Obtener los últimos  10 registros:

```
$var= "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: wooo, me sirvio muchas gracias, solo me faltaba el LIMIT 10, efectivamente era en la consulta SQL.